# Several questions about the proof of this lemma

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces, harmonic-analysis

I am reading [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266751575_Tight_wavelet_frames_on_local_fields). I have Several questions about the proof of the lemma 3.3.

How to Prove 1,2,3,4?

[image]
[image]

Comment: The inequality in 2 looks like an application of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, isn't it?

Comment: Yes somedeal ..